# Algorithm for slicing planes (in place) out of an array of RGB values

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, image-processing, slice

I've got a flat array of byte RGB values that goes `R1 G1 B1 R2 G2 B2 R3 G3 B3 ... Rn Gn Bn`.  So my data looks like:

```
char imageData[WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3];
```

But I want to pass a WIDTH*HEIGHT array to an existing C library that expects a single plane of this data.  That would be a sequence of just the R values (or just the G, or just the B).

It's easy enough to allocate a new array and copy the data (duh).  But the images are very large.  If it weren't a C library but took some kind of iteration interface to finesse the "slicing" traversal, that would be great.  But I can't edit the code I'm calling...it wants a plain old pointer to a block of sequential memory.

HOWEVER I have write access to this array.  It is viable to create a routine that would sort it into color planes.  I'd also need a reverse transformation that would put it back, but by definition the same method that sorted it into planes could be applied to unsort it.

How efficiently can I (in place) turn this array into `R1 R2 R3 ... Rn G1 G2 G3 ... Gn B1 B2 B3 ... Bn` and then back again?  Any non-naive algorithms?

Comment: You are talking about transposing a 3xN matrix.  The naive transpose operation is inefficient because it's full of cache misses.  Google for "cache-efficient transpose".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition#Algorithms

Comment: well to be honest i think you should consider just allocating more memory..as a in place transposition for non square matrix is nasty

Comment: @DeadMG C++.  I actually think I understand the problem pretty well (including the trick that scrambling to get just *one* of the planes sorted with the only requirement to be reversibility can be a trivial operation...which is why I'm only discussing the harder problem).  I'm just contemplating clever alternatives, such as those which would require (say) just WIDTH bytes or just HEIGHT bytes of overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This paper ["A Simple In-Place Algorithm for In-Shuffle"](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598) describes how to transpose matrix of 2*N and gives a hint how to do it for other cases, so 3*N may be also possible. [This answer to other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529396/1009831) shows that it is indeed possible.

Or use an algorithm which writes each value to its transposed place, then does the same for the value from that place, and so on until cycle is connected. Flag processed values in a bit vector. And continue until this vector is all 1s.

Both algorithms are not cache-friendly. Probably some clever use of PREFETCH instruction can improve this.

**Edit:**

C++, RGB to single planes, not optimized:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

enum {N = 8};

void transpose(std::vector<char>& a)
{
  std::bitset<3*N> b;

  for (int i = 1; i < 3*N; ++i)
  {
    if (b[i])
      continue;

    int ptr = i;
    int next;
    char nextVal = a[i];

    do {
      next = ptr/3 + N*(ptr%3);
      char prevVal = nextVal;
      nextVal = a[next];
      a[next] = prevVal;
      ptr = next;
      b[ptr] = true;
    }
    while (ptr != i);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<char> a(3*N);

  for (int i = 0; i != 3*N; ++i)
    a[i] = i;

  transpose(a);

  for (int i = 0; i != 3*N; ++i)
    std::cout << (int)a[i] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

My original intent is to use a bit vector of size WIDTH*HEIGHT, which gives overhead of WIDTH*HEIGHT/8. But it is always possible to sacrifice speed for space. The bit vector may be of size WIDTH or HEIGHT or any desirable value, even 0. The trick is to maintain a pointer to the cell, before which all values are transposed. The bit vector is for cells, starting from this pointer. After it is all 1s, It is moved to next position, then all the algorithm steps are performed except actual data movement. And the bit vector is ready to continue transposing. This variant is O(N^2) instead of O(N).

**Edit2:**

PREFITCH optimization is not difficult to implement: just calculate indexes, invoke PREFETCH, and put indexes to a queue (ringbuffer), then get indexes from the queue and move data.

**Edit3:**

The idea of other algorithm, which is O(1) size, O(N*log(N)) time, is cache-friendly and may be faster than "cycle" algorithm (for image sizes < 1Gb):

- Split N*3 matrix to several 3*3 matrices of char and transpose them
- Split the result to 3*3 matrices of char[3] and transpose them
- Continue while matrices size is less than the array size
- Now we have up to 3*2*log3(N) ordered pieces. Join them.
- First join pieces of equal size. Very simple "cycles" of length 4 may be used.
- Join unequal-sized pieces with reverse(reverse(a), reverse(b))

Comment: +1 thanks for the paper.  Although "in-shuffle" seems like a strange thing to call it...I would generally say that "shuffling" is understood to be a randomizing operation.  Terminologically speaking, I think you and @OliCharlesworth have nailed it better by categorizing it as a matrix transposition.  I'd be interested to see a "cycle-processing" version with a bit vector that actually worked, everything I've considered in that area has been a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need one plane, this seems pretty easy. If you need all 3 you will probably have better luck with a more sophisticated algorithm.

```
void PlanarizeR(char * imageData, int width, int height)
{
    char *in = imageData;
    int pixelCount = width * height;
    for (int i = 0;  i < pixelCount;  ++i, in+=3)
        std::swap(*in, imageData[i])
}
```

It shouldn't be too hard to run the loop backwards from high to low to reverse the process.

Comment: Yup, good point!  Though I know about this (per earlier comment to DeadMG).  The separation that gets all three is the question that interests me here.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *imageData = malloc (WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3 * sizeof(char));
```

this function do this R1 R2 R3 ... Rn G1 G2 G3 ... Gn B1 B2 B3 ... Bn,,

```
char *toRGB(char *imageData, int WIDTH, int HEIGHT){
    int len = WIDTH * HEIGHT;
    char *RGB = malloc (len * sizeof(char));
    int i, j = 0,flag = 0;

    for(i=0 ; i<=len ; i++, j+=3){
        if(j<len)
            RGB[i] = imageData[j];
        else{
            switch(flag){
                case 0: j=-2; flag=1; break;   // j=-2 the next iteration will start at j=1
                case 1: j=-1; break;   // j=-1 the next iteration will start at j=2
            }
        }
    }
    return RGB;
}
```

Comment: This is a naive transpose operation, but written in a really obtuse manner.

Comment: aha,, so he need no memory allocation,, ok,, i'll edit this now !!

Comment: Why did you write it with a state machine? Noone could ready this code and understand it at the same time.